# How to loop though elements in XML with namespace using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

The topic of this question may be incorrect as I am new in XSLT. I will try to explain with an example. I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Recordset Name="Report" xmlns="http://pia.com/xml/ns">
    <Record>
        <TransactionReferenceNumber>T00005546</TransactionReferenceNumber>
        <ExecutingEntityIDCode>724500LY73GPE4GDX159</ExecutingEntityIDCode>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <TransactionReferenceNumber>P00098080</TransactionReferenceNumber>
        <ExecutingEntityIDCode>66666</ExecutingEntityIDCode>
    </Record>
</Recordset>
```

XLST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
          xmlns:a="http://pia.com/xml/ns" 
          exclude-result-prefixes="a">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" 
              encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"  />
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="/a:Recordset/a:Record">
          <TxId>
            <xsl:value-of select="/a:Recordset/a:Record/a:TransactionReferenceNumber"/>
          </TxId><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          <ExctgPty>
              <xsl:value-of select="/a:Recordset/a:Record/a:ExecutingEntityIDCode"/>
          </ExctgPty>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With desired output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TxId>T00005546</TxId>
<ExctgPty>724500LY73GPE4GDX159</ExctgPty>
<TxId>P00098080</TxId>
<ExctgPty>66666</ExctgPty>
```

But I am getting the first data in both cases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TxId>T00005546</TxId>
<ExctgPty>724500LY73GPE4GDX159</ExctgPty>
<TxId>T00005546</TxId>
<ExctgPty>724500LY73GPE4GDX159</ExctgPty>
```

How do i loop and get the desired output? 
NOTE: This is just a small chuck of XML and XSLT code which I am using.

Comment: Show us the XSL.  I'm not sure what kind of help you expect if you don't show what you've done.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add. I will add

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<xsl:for-each select="/a:Recordset/a:Record">
        <TxId>
            <xsl:value-of select="a:TransactionReferenceNumber"/>
        </TxId><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <ExctgPty>
            <xsl:value-of select="a:ExecutingEntityIDCode"/>
        </ExctgPty>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: @abhishekshakya, when you run for-each condition than in loop you are at the position of current element, therefore you don't need to write full xpath for child element, it can be reffered only by child element name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://pia.com/xml/ns" exclude-result-prefixes="a">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="a:TransactionReferenceNumber">
    <TxId>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </TxId>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="a:ExecutingEntityIDCode">
    <ExctgPty>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    </ExctgPty>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would

- use xsl:apply-templates instead of xsl:for-each
- took advantage of default templates that will traverse entire XML tree except attributes
- write template only for the elements a:TransactionReferenceNumber and 
  a:ExecutingEntityIDCode to change element name and add line feed character.